# selenium webdriver method findElement give Unable to locate element:

Tags: selenium, junit4

I'm new in testing with selenium (IDE and WebDriver) and Junit i'm facing this problem:

1. First , i'v learnt how to use selenium IDE with firefox plugin
2. I create a maven project in Eclipse
3. Then i used selenium IDE to export the code as  java/junit4/webDriver
4. In eclipse i create a class with  code crated by selenium IDE :

   ```
   public class PB01_TTT {
     private WebDriver driver;
     private String baseUrl;
     private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
     private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
     WebElement element;

     @Before()
     public void setUp() throws Exception {
       driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       baseUrl = "https://w8a.prv:9431";
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

     }
   ```

   @Test
     public void testPBO1TTT() throws Exception {

   ```
       driver.get(baseUrl + "/ProcessPortal/login.jsp");
       driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
       driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("user");
       driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
       driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");

       driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.submit-text")).click();
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);

       String columnToDisplayXpath = "//html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a";

       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(columnToDisplayXpath)));

       element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(columnToDisplayXpath));

       Assert.assertNotNull(element);
   ```
5. Now when i run my test as junit test all code works until the method --> driver.findElement . It gives to me this error

   > org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a"}
6. In debug the By.xpath retrieve the element, i'v tried also the By.cssSelector ,but nothig changed. It's the driver findelement that doesn't work.

Any help will be really appraciated

Comment: Seemns the element was not found.You need to avoid using absolute xpath's. Add the html section of the link if you need help in getting the selector.

Comment: Until i know yuo can get element by --> ID, Name, Link Text, Css selector , DOM ,xpath . I've never heard to get by html sectiomn, could you please explain better ? thank you

Comment: HI you are waiting for <a> element.  Try to find element                                               by.linkText() or by.partialLinkText() instead of xpath

Comment: where do i have to find it ? how ?

Comment: is not this the problem , all the By.xpath, By.cssSelector, or By linkk work, is the driver.findelement that doesn't work

Comment: I was saying to copy/paste the html section in the question if you need help. To get the basics of selectors for xpath http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp , for css http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: You could have css selector like a[href*='part_of_href_value']

Comment: is not this the problem , all the By.xpath, By.cssSelector, or By linkk work, is the driver.findelement that doesn't work